# How do I create a decorator that adds a logged in user to the function?

Tags: django

I am writing tests for views that require the user to be logged. I want to write a decorator to **add** a logged in user to each test.

For example, rather than writing:

```
    def test_view_url(cls):
        get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='Paulian', password='yGy2pl12')
        cls.client.login(username='Paulian', password='yGy2pl12')
        response = cls.client.get(cls.home_view_url)
        cls.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
```

I want to write:

```
    @user_is_logged_in
    def test_view_url(cls):
        response = cls.client.get(cls.home_view_url)
        cls.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
```

Here is my current and faulty decorator:

```
def user_is_logged_in(func) -> object:
    def wrapper(func):
        c = Client()
        if c.login(username='Paulian', password='yGy2pl12'):
            pass
        else:
            get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='Paulian', password='yGy2pl12')
            c.login(username='Paulian', password='yGy2pl12')
        return wrapper
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Can't you just do that in `setUp`?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks Daniel; that's the simpler and cleaner solution. Shall I close the question?